# Racket: Custom predicate to use within contract

Tags: date, scheme, racket, predicate, contract

I'm writing small pet project in Racket and using [Gregor](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/index.html) lib to handle dates.

I have function that accepts two dates (from Gregor, not standard library) and I would like to add contract for it. Contract should say that date from first argument has to be less/earlier than date from second argument.

In Gregor we can achieve it by using [(date<=? x y)](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/date.html#%28def._%28%28lib._gregor%2Fmain..rkt%29._date~3c~3d~3f%29%29) or similar predicate, but I cannot understand how to combine it with contracts.

```
 (contract-out
          [process-dates (->i ([x date?]
                               [y (x) (and/c date?
                                             (date>=? x))])])
```

will not work, and there is no out-of-box `date>=?/c` predicate.

So I guess that I will need to write such predicates by my own, therefore I would like to know how to do it. I've looked through Racket sources and found that standard features are [quite complicated](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/ed2381ee595fa8ac06dded9aacaa4c34f5d73475/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/and.rkt) to reproduce.

Is there simpler way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `lambda`:

```
(->i ([x date?]
      [y (x) (and/c date? (lambda (y) (date>=? y x)))])
     [_ any/c])
```

One disadvantage is that if the contract is violated, the error message will include a `???` in place of the lambda expression. If you want it to print something more meaningful there, you can do something like the following:

```
(define (date>=/c x)
  (flat-named-contract
   `(date>=/c ,x)
   (lambda (y) (date>=? y x))))
....
(->i ([x date?]
      [y (x) (and/c date? (date>=/c x))])
     [_ any/c])
```

If you want even finer control over the error message, you could try using [`flat-contract-with-explanation`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html).

Comment: Perfect! Error message is indeed not very useful, but as for Racket7.3 at least I can see lambda expression in trace.

Answer (score 3):

While Ryan's answer is great, I've found that one may solve this problem in following manner, using precondition:

```
(->i ([x date?]
      [y date?])
    #:pre (x y) (date<=? x y)
    ;; ...
 )
```